# Progress bar not updating on a separate form

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am trying to make a progress bar on a separate form when doing other tasks in my application. everything opens up and shows correctly but progress bar is not updating. I tried background worker with no joy. Code is in VB.net

Please help. I must be missing a step or two in my code.

What I am trying to do is when listview is clicked, takes a bit to populate textboxes out of my excel database, so I would like the another form to open and update progress bar accordingly.

Hope someone can help.

This is my Click Event:

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    frmProgress.Show()
    AddToDatabaseToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
    frmProgress.Close()
End Sub
```

Then I have Background Worker code as follows:

```
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        showData()
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(100 * i / 100), "Running..." & i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    frmProgress.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                                                 ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
                                                 Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    ' Called when the BackgroundWorker is completed.
    Label1.Text = "Loading... Done"
End Sub
```

Then my Progress form Load event is this:

```
Private Sub frmProgress_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    With ProgressBar1
        .Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Me.Text = "IDB"
    Label1.Text = "Loading... Please wait"
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
End Sub
```

ShowData() is in the module and is the code that is loading and takes few seconds to load.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"Code is in VB.net"*. What code? I don't see any code. How can we tell what you did wrong if we can't see what you did?

Comment: That said, it may be worth your while to check [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567) out.

Comment: I will send the code tonight when I am back at my station.

Comment: Can someone please have a look at the original question and maybe give some answers. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly work. You call `Show` on the form and that returns immediately, at which point you call `Close` on that same form. I have provided you with a link that shows how to do this properly. It is tried and tested. I suggest that you use it.

Comment: Thank you for your help – jmcilhinney. I have found some other solutions to my problem.